# replacing text in an sql file using variables

Tags: sql

i have an sql file that I want to update via ssh script.  I'm trying to replace some text in there using sed.  I don't get errors, but the text is not replacing.  Here's the code I'm using.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "enter theme: "
read theme
echo -n "enter username: "
read user
echo -n "enter domain/url: "
read url

cd /home/$theme/

sed -i 's/\/{$theme}/\/{$user}/g' ./$theme.sql
sed -i 's/{$theme}.domain.net/{$url}/g' ./$theme.sql
```

So, I'm trying to replace the current text ($theme variable) with the new variables $user and $url in the sql file i reference.

Here's the sql snippet of what it will be sifting through and updating:

```
LOCK TABLES `ivg4_options` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `ivg4_options` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `ivg4_options` VALUES (1,'siteurl','http://megashop.domain.net/','yes'),(2,'blogname','Woo Commerce','yes'),(3,'blogdescription','Just another WooCommerce site','yes'),(37,'home','http://megashop.domain.net','yes'),(38,'category_base','','yes'),(40,'advanced_edit','0','yes'),(41,'comment_max_links','2','yes'),(42,'gmt_offset','0','yes'),(43,'default_email_category','1','yes'),(52,'use_trackback','0','yes'),(53,'default_role','subscriber','yes'),(54,'db_version','33055','yes'),(55,'uploads_use_yearmonth_folders','1','yes'),(56,'upload_path','/home/megashop/public_html/wp-content/uploads','yes')
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the contents of this sql script? It'd be helpful to see what text these sed lines are supposed to be acting on.

Comment: i just did.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's better. So "megashop" is an example of a theme?

Comment: yes.  and there are others too, hence the dynamic variable.

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of the "{" and "}". You don't need them.

The second problem is: `-i` requires an argument (at least some versions... it seems to be the case here), so you have to provide at least an empty string `''` if you want to ignore it. From the `sed` man page:

> ```
>  -i extension
>          Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.
>          If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.  It
>          is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place
>          editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situ-
>          ations where disk space is exhausted, etc.
> ```

Normally it yields a somewhat cryptic error message saying "sed: -i may not be used with stdin". You might have missed this…

This is the final script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "enter theme: "
read theme
echo -n "enter username: "
read user
echo -n "enter domain/url: "
read url

cd /home/$theme/

sed -i '' 's/\/$theme/\/$user/g' ./$theme.sql
sed -i '' 's/$theme.domain.net/$url/g' ./$theme.sql
```

Comment: ok ran this script and got this:  
    root@classic30 [~]# /dbtest.sh
    enter wordpress theme (terra, megashop: megashop
    enter username: usertest
    enter domain/url : test.test.net/stage
    sed: can't read s/\/$theme/\/$user/g: No such file or directory
    sed: can't read s/$theme.domain.net/$url/g: No such file or directory